# Can single variables be called prime factors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, prime-factorization

**Prime factor decomposition** of a term like 10y²z³ gives some prime numbers and single variables, e.g., 2×5×y×y×z×z×z. In this example, 2 and 5 can be called **prime factors**, can't they? Can y and z be called **prime factors** also? If "no," is there one name suitable both for the prime numbers and single variables that we obtain after the prime factor decomposition? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'm going to guess and say yes, x is a prime factor.  Obviously, further on down the line, if x becomes an integer it might factor differently or further, but if that's the entire context, then x would be "prime".

Comment: Some people would argue that irreducible polynomials behave much like primes (depending on the context).

Comment: Some people would say irreducible polynomials are the generalisation of primes for polynomials of the variable being a generalised number.

Comment: Thank you a bunch! Personally, I'd call them 'irreducible monomial factors' or maybe  'irreducible polynomials.' Not sure about the accepted term though.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.